# Generate random strings of fixed length from given characters with equal occurance

Tags: python, random, fixed

I want to generate random strings from a list of characters C (e.g. C = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']). This random string shall have length N (e.g. N = 32). Every character should occur equally often - in that example 8 times.

How can I implement that each character occurs equally often in here:

```
''.join(random.choice(C) for i in range(N))
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the way you are doing it.

Comment: Yup looks good the way it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can guarantee that each item is picked with the same frequency if you use `random.choice`.  Each choice is equally likely which isn't the same thing.

The best way to do this would be to maintain a list of characters and shuffle it...

```
characters = C * 8
random.shuffle(characters)
print(''.join(characters))
```

Or, if you want a bunch of them:

```
def get_random_strings(characters, count, N):
    """Yield `N` strings that contain each character in `characters` `count` times."""
    characters = list(characters) * count
    for _ in xrange(N):
        random.shuffle(characters)
        yield ''.join(characters)
```